# É possível passar o valor de uma variável Javascript para uma variável do C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

A ideia é a seguinte, utilizar o javascript para detectar a resolução da tela, e pegar o valor da variável deste javascript e passar para a variável do C#. A única coisa que me passou na cabeça é criar um input para manipular as variáveis, mas acredito que tenha outro método. Na prática a ideia seria mais ou menos esta:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var varJavascrpt = $(window).width();
    </script>
    @{
        var varCSharp = varJavascript;
    }
```

Comment: Você planeja obter a resolução para controlar o layout da página?

Comment: Sim, você já faz isso o tempo na aplicação. O mais comum é usar AJAX nesses casos. Nem sei qual é duplicata disto, mas já foi respondido algumas vezes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net-mvc%5D+ajax

Comment: @rodorgas a idéia é que eu tenho um componente na navbar, e quando do a resolução diminuísse,  o conteúdo ficasse oculto

Answer (score 1):

Para passar valores do JavaScript para o asp.net, é necessário fazer uma nova requisição (e.g. usando AJAX). Não é possível verificar a resolução antes de fazer a requisição porque JS nesse caso é client-side, enquanto asp.net é server-side, o que significa que o código JS só será executado no navegador após terminado o pedido que transferiu a página. O servidor não tem acesso ao código independente do JS executado no navegador, a não ser que você informe ele diretamente fazendo uma nova requisição.

Mas essa abordagem é ruim, porque a decisão de exibir ou não um componente na navbar ficará dependente de uma segunda requisição após o carregamento da página. O ideal é fazer isso com tecnologias client-side para não ter que ir até o servidor e depois voltar, economizando assim recursos, acelerando o carregamento da página e não dependendo de JS habilitado no navegador.

É possível fazer isso com JS, mas o CSS3 introduziu o [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries), iniciando o movimento de layouts responsivos que se ajustam automaticamente de acordo com a resolução (e o servidor é agnóstico em relação à isso). Por exemplo, para esconder um navbar quando a resolução for menor ou igual a 600px, faça assim:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) 
{
  .navbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Entendi... valeu rodorgas